# how can i calculate p value of miRNA raw reads counts using R?

Tags: r, p-values

working on lung cancer project and need to find out which genes are deferentially expressed and which are not. for that i a have downloaded miRNA data set from GEO id is GSE110907. And the file i got has to variable gene_id and read counts. from that i have to derive p value from that data/file.[image]

Comment: For context, this question was already asked at biostars https://www.biostars.org/p/417111/, with some follow-up comments.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by re-formulating the question in this post: Your end-goal seems to the differential expression analysis (DEA) of your samples (and you have to have to levels for this like treatment-control, mutant-WT, etc ...). P-values are context-dependent and should be calculated based on your research question/hypothesis.

DEA has been addressed by many researchers and `R` has a lot of packages to help you with this; `DESeq2`, `edgeR`, `limma`, etc ...

I would go to the `Biconductor` website, search for one of the three above, and go through their rich **vignettes** and would come back here for **specific** questions.